# Firebase Facebook login with redirect returning null email

Tags: javascript, facebook, firebase, firebase-authentication

If I have the following code

```js
function facebookSignin(){

  var provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
  provider.addScope('email');
  firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider);
  
}

firebase.auth().getRedirectResult().then(function(result) {

    if (result.credential) {
      var token = result.credential.accessToken;
    }
    var user = result.user;
    console.log(result);

  }).catch(function(error) {

    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
    var email = error.email;
    var credential = error.credential;
    console.log(errorMessage);
    
  });
```

I'm trying to get the email from Facebook login however when I print the user object i get a `null` email. I have included a screenshot of the user object printed in the console

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Seeing the same thing with Google login as seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40570200/firebase-facebook-login-with-redirect-returning-null-email)

Answer (score 0):

Check the content of firebase.auth().currentUser.providerData[0].email. That should show the facebook email. It is possible you have enabled "multiple accounts per email" in the Firebase console. The default for new projects is single account per email. For migrating Firebase projects from the previous version, they are set to "multiple accounts per email". That will only set firebase.auth().currentUser.email for password accounts. For federated accounts, it is set to null. There is another possibility that the facebook account you are using is a phone number account or has chosen not to disclose the email.