# ionic3+firebase+angularfire2 facebook email null with Multiple accounts per email address

Tags: facebook, firebase, firebase-authentication, ionic3, angularfire2

In my firebase dashboard I have set multiple accounts for one email option.

[firebase dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFEE4.jpg)

The configuration of Angularfire2 is the standard so I do not hit the code of app.modules.ts

home.ts

```
facebookir(){
let goPagePrehome:boolean = false;
let userDB:any;
firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider())
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res);
    console.info(JSON.stringify(res));
    this.userService.getUsers()
    .forEach((users) => {
      users.forEach((user) =>{
            if(user['user_email'] == res.additionalUserInfo.profile.email){
              // console.log('res.additionalUserInfo.profile.email');
              // console.log(user);
              userDB = user;
              goPagePrehome= true;
            }
      });
      if(goPagePrehome){
        this.goNextPagePrehome(userDB);
      }else{
        this.singup();
      }
    });
  }); }
```

In the previous code, the user's email is created and verified in our database. And is sent to the record "this.singup ();" Or to the home "this.goNextPagePrehome (userDB);"

sign.ts

```
this.afAuth.authState.subscribe( user => {
    console.log('find user facebook 2');
    console.log(user);
    if (user){
      if(user.providerData["0"].providerId == "facebook.com"){
        if(this.userData['picture'] == '' || this.userData['picture'] ==  undefined || this.userData['picture']== null){ 
          console.info('find user facebook 2 - si');
          this.userData['name']=this.userData['username']= user.providerData["0"].displayName;
          this.userData['email']=  user.providerData["0"].email;
          this.userData['picture']=  user.providerData["0"].photoURL;
          console.log(this.userData);
        }
      }
      //this.envioCorreoFacebook();
    } else {
      console.info('find user facebook 2 - no');
    }
  });
```

As you can see in both files I am verifying the mail for the data supplied by the provider as "providerData [" 0 "]" and "res.additionalUserInfo.profile.email".
The firebase response is:
[firebase images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4loiO.jpg)


I need your help to correct this problem that some facebook accounts work with firebase.?

Comment: As you can see used the recommended by this contribution. : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40570200/firebase-facebook-login-with-redirect-returning-null-email

Comment: It could be that the Facebook account doesn't have an email. Also can you try to request the email scope when signing in with Facebook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the mail again; although by default it should bring it to all facebook accounts.

```
var provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
    provider.addScope('email');
    firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider)
      .then(res => {...});
```